# What events will happen in past and future Kalpas and all Manus from current Kalpa are remain in all Kalpas?

Tags: identification-request, manu, kalpa

I know we're currently live in Sveta Varaha Kalpa. I had confusion with Manus, if they remain in all Kalpas or any other diffrent Manus?

And, I know Sati was born in the past Pitru Kalpa. Like this, any scriptures mentiones about other events happened in previous Kalpas and the events will happen in future Kalpas?

Please clear my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If they remain in all Kalpas or any other diffrent Manus?
```

Actually, all Manus of current Kalpa are not remain in all Kalpas. However, Svayambhuva Manu is already Manu in Pitr Kalpa, according to [this chapter](https://%20https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626807.html) of Skanda Purana.

And, Lord Shani will become Manu of next Kalpa. It is mentioned in [this chapter](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c049.htm) of Mahabharata:-

> Surya's son Sani (Saturn) will, in a future Kalpa, take birth as the great Manu of that period. During that Manwantara, O son, thou shalt, in respect of merits, be superior to even the Manus of the several periods.

```
Like this, any scriptures mentiones about other events happened in previous Kalpas and the events will happen in future Kalpas?
```

Let's see about some of events happened in previous Kalpas.

1. In [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423751.html) of Skanda Purana, Kubera performed a penance to Vishwanatha and Vishalakshi from Padma Kalpa until beginning of Meghavahana Kalpa.

> 133. In the **Padma Kalpa** formerly, O Brāhmaṇa, Viśravas was born of Pulastya, a mental son of Brahmā. His son was Vaiśravaṇa.
> 134. This city of Alakā created by Viśvakṛt was enjoyed by him by propitiating Lord Tryaṃbaka (three-eyed) formerly, by means of severe austerities.
> 135. When that Kalpa had passed by and **Meghavāhana Kalpa began**, this son of Yajñadatta (i.e., Guṇanidhi), the donor of wealth, performed a severe penance.

2. Lord Vishnu took the form of cloud at Megavahana Kalpa. It is mentioned in [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-linga-purana/d/doc1195250.html) of Linga Purana.

> 16-18. O brahmin, your doubt is reasonable. I shall tell you the cause of the same that happened to Brahmā in the Tatpuruṣa kalpa. After pondering over all things the supreme lord created Brahmā. In the **Meghavāhana kalpa, Viṣṇu, the lord of the universe, became a cloud** and bore the supreme lord Śiva for a thousand years with ease and comfort.

3. Before incarnates as Sati, Devi took seventeeth avatars to sake of blessing the world. [This chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626794.html) from Skanda Purana mention it.

And, now let see about events will happen in future Kalpas.

1. Lord Vishnu will incarnate as a fish in beginning of next Kalpa, according to [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626789.html) from Skanda Purana.

> 20-23. When all the worlds were completely burned, at the time of Pralaya, Kṛṣṇa, in the form of the infinite one, collected together the four Vedas along with their Aṅgas, the Purāṇas, the detailed texts of Nyāya, Mīmāṃsās and Dharmaśāstra and retained them within himself. At the beginning of the next Kalpa, he, assuming the form of **a fish in the vast ocean**, told the entire tract of lores to Brahmā, endowed with divine vision. Brahmā endowed with the knowledge and vision of the three divisions of time (past, present and future) narrated it to all sages. Thereafter, all the scriptures and Purāṇas became current.

I hope your doubt was cleared by my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to Hindu cosmology, the universe undergoes cycles of creation and dissolution, known as Kalpas. Each Kalpa is presided over by a specific Brahma, and within each Kalpa, there are different Manus who act as the progenitors and lawgivers for that particular cycle.

In each Kalpa, a new Manu emerges to govern the world and its inhabitants. The Manus are considered the progenitors of humanity and play a crucial role in the preservation and administration of the universe during their respective periods. Each Manu is believed to rule for the duration of one Manvantara, which is a specific period of time within a Kalpa.

Specifically, you can refer to the Vishnu Purana, Shiva Purana, Brahma Purana, and Bhagavata Purana for cosmological descriptions and accounts of previous and future Kalpas. These Puranas often contain sections dedicated to explaining the cyclic nature of the universe and the role of various deities, including Brahma, Vishnu, and Shiva.

Comment: Hmm... But, You may show some of events of past/future Kalpas from the scriptures.

Comment: Samudra Manthan: This event is described in the Puranas, particularly in the Bhagavata Purana and the Mahabharata. It narrates the story of the gods (Devas) and demons (Asuras) coming together to churn the cosmic ocean in order to obtain the nectar of immortality (Amrita). The churning is performed using Mount Mandara as the churning rod and Vasuki, the serpent, as the churning rope.
This event symbolizes the cyclical nature of creation and destruction, as well as the constant struggle between good and evil forces in the universe.

Comment: While this particular event does not explicitly describe the entire cycle of kalpas, it reflects the recurring themes of creation and rejuvenation found in Hindu cosmology.